# Changing default overlay behaviour to not return to the top of the screen

Tags: 7, navigation, modal-dialogs

I have a custom module which displays a page as an overlay, however when you click on the link it displays the overlay but the background page now returns to the top.

This behaviour can be seen when clicking on any of the Drupal admin options whilst scrolled slightly down the page, it then jumps back to the top of the scroll when displaying the admin overlay.

Is there any way I can disable this for the overlay page defined in my module?